# General boundary condition for the parabolic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Looking for the solution of this problem:
Let $\Omega\subset R^d$ be a Lipschitz domain, $T>0$ be given and denote $Q := (0, T) \times Ω.$ Assume that $A\in L^\infty(\Omega;R^{d\times d}_{sym})$ be elliptic matrix and $f\in L^2(0, T;L^2(\Omega)), b\in L^2(0, T;L^\infty(\Omega))$ and $g\in L^2(0,T;L^2(\partial\Omega))$ be given.
Consider the problem
$$\partial_t u − div (A\nabla u) = f, \quad\text{in } Q,$$
$$(A \nabla u) \vec{\nu} + bu = g \quad\text{on } \Gamma := (0, T) \times \partial \Omega,$$
$$u(0, x) = u_0(x) \quad\text{in } \Omega,$$
where $u_0 \in L^2(\Omega).$

First we would like to define a notion of a weak solution for general setting. Assume that $b \geq 0$ and prove the existence and the uniqueness of the weak solution.

The secend goal is: Assume that $b \geq \varepsilon > 0 \text{ a.e. on } \Gamma$ and $f \in L^2_{loc}(0,\infty;L^2(\Omega)),$ $b \in L^2_{loc}(0,\infty;L^\infty(\partial\Omega)),$ $g \in L^2_{loc}(0,\infty;L^2(\partial\Omega)) $ and satisfies for some $\tau > 0$ that $f(t, x) = f(t + τ, x)$ for almost all $(t, x) \in (0, \infty)\times\Omega$ and $g(t, x) = g(t + \tau, x)$ and $b(t, x) = b(t + \tau, x)$ for almost all $(t, x) \in (0, \infty) \times \partial\Omega$, i.e. $f, b$ and $g$ are time periodic with the period $\tau.$ Show that there exists unique $u_0 \in L^2(\Omega),$ for which
the weak solution $u$ satisfies $u(t, x) = u(t +\tau, x),$ i.e. there is a unique initial data for which there is unique periodic solution.

The last goal is to improve the result of the first goal and prove the existence and the uniqueness without the assumption $b \geq 0$ and for arbitrary $f \in L^1(0, T;L^2(\Omega))$ and $g \in L^{\frac{4}{3}}(0, T;L^2(\partial\Omega)).$ Then consider $f = 0,$ $g = 1,$ $b = 1$ and look for the behaviour of $u(t)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. As stated, this question does not provide information on what you have tried to do to solve the problem, and where specifically do you struggle. Questions asking for homework solutions are against the guidelines of the website and will be closed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.